# Create new column based on row values scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a data frame with several columns. I want to create a new column based on the following idea:
If there is one 0 in the row, put 0 in the new column, otherwise, put 1

```
+-------+--------+-----+
|A      |B       |C    |
+-------+--------+-----+
|     1 |      1 |   1 | 
|     1 |      0 |   1 | 
+-------+--------+-----+
```

Desired output:

```
+-------+--------+-----+-------+
|A      |B       |C    |New_Col|
+-------+--------+-----+-------+
|     1 |      1 |   1 |   1   |
|     1 |      0 |   1 |   0   |
+-------+--------+-----+-------+
```

I ahve tried to .reduce and sum values and then compare .size and sum values, but failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `when` function to add a column conditionally in a spark dataframe

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("test").getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val someDF = Seq(
      (1,1,1),
      (1,0,1),
      (1,1,1)).toDF("a","b","c")

someDF.withColumn("new",when($"a" + $"b" + $"c" ===lit(3),1).otherwise(0)).show()
```

Here is how the output looks like

```
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|new|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  1|  1|
|  1|  0|  1|  0|
|  1|  1|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: what if number of columns more than 10?

Comment: add all 10 columns

Comment: you have to do the check basing on number of input columns. You never specified that there can be 10 columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `when` and `otherwise` using OR condition.

```
    val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq((1,1,0), (1,2,3),(2,5,0))).toDF("a","b","c")
    df.withColumn("d", when(col("a") === 0 or col("b") === 0 or col("c") === 0, lit(0)).otherwise(lit(1))).show()
```

You can evaluate columns dynamically based on list of columns too.

```
    val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq((1,1,0), (1,2,3),(2,5,0))).toDF("a","b","c")

    val cols = Seq("a","b","c")
    val initCol = lit(0)===1
    val col1 = cols.foldLeft(initCol)((x,y) => x or col(y) ===0)

    df.withColumn("d", when(col1, lit(0)).otherwise(lit(1))).show()
```

Result

```
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  0|  0|
|  1|  2|  3|  1|
|  2|  5|  0|  0|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: what if number of columns more than 10?

Comment: you dynamically do this check too. I will give an example.

Answer (score 1):

using a when otherwise function may do the trick `df.withColumn("NewCol", when(col("A") === 0,0).when(col("B") === 0,0).when(col("C") === 0,0).otherwise(1))`

Comment: what if number of columns more than 10?